# Is it possible to directly retrieve statuses from a public twitter list using the API?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been trying to fetch the statuses from a list (public list), but I could not find any specific method in the twitter api documentation from this. The way to fetch tweets from a list, is described as going through the user (the creator of the list) and fetching the statuses then, something like http://api.twitter.com/version/:user/lists/:id/statuses.format

Is there no direct way to get the statuses from a public list...something like maybe http://api.twitter.com/version/:list_id/statuses.format or http://api.twitter.com/version/lists/:id/statuses.format

This might be a trivial question, but would certainly help eliminating the user dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but a list is maintained by a user, and you must reference it in the context of the user that created the list, like so:

`http://api.twitter.com/1/dotnetdevbuzz/lists/source-users/statuses.json?page=1`

where *dotnetdevbuzz* is the user, and *source-users* is the list slug.

At least you don't have to be authenticated in order to get the most recent statuses from the list members.